# phpMailer certificate verify failed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, xampp, phpmailer, amazon-ses

Im using XAMPP on windows 10, My site is using the Yii 1 framework, and is hosted on amazon, I'm using gsuite for the company email. To allow emails to be sent out using my domain i'm also using amazon SES.

This is my code to send out email. It works on live, but not on my local

```
                $mail = new YiiMailer();

                $mail->clearLayout();//if layout is already set in config
                $mail->setViewPath('application.views.mail');
                $mail->setFrom(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'], $model->firstname.' '.$model->lastname);
                $mail->setTo($model->email);
                $mail->setSubject('Contact Us Question');

                if (YII_DEBUG) {
                    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                            'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                    );
                }

                $mail->setView('contact');
                $mail->setData(
                    array(
                        'email' => $model->email,
                        'message' => $model->body, 
                        'name' => $model->firstname.' '.$model->lastname, 
                        'description' => 'Customer Contact'
                    )
                );

                
                if ($mail->send()) { }
```

When i try sending an email i get this error message

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

I found solutions that suggested to add this code (which i did) still same issue

```
if (YII_DEBUG) {
                    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                            'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                    );
                }
```

i also changed this in my php.ini ([cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem))

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem"

[openssl]

openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem"
```

my mail settings are

```
'Mailer' => 'smtp',
'Host' => 'email-smtp.********.amazonaws.com',
'Port' => 587,
'SMTPSecure' => 'tls',
'SMTPAuth' => true,
'Username' => '*************',
'Password' => '*************',
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: I know exactly what's wrong: you didn't read [the docs on this exact problem](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure). Turning off verification doesn't fix anything, it just hides the problem while leaving you vulnerable. It's most likely that your OS needs updates applying to get the latest CA certificates, or that you need to install root certificates manually, all of which is described in the docs.

Comment: well i just want to test my mail on local. thats why i turned it off. i also changed the `curl.cainfo` and `openssl.cafile` in my php.ini still no luck

Comment: It's pointless to use TLS when connecting to `localhost`, and you won't find anyone that will issue you a certificate for that anyway, however you may need to turn off opportunistic TLS by setting `$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;`. Note that this does *not* apply if you are talking to a remote AWS SMTP server as the code you posted is doing.